# SQL Server fast random sampling

Tags: sql-server

I have been looking for methods for fast sampling from sql table and I found this very useful article:

https://www.sisense.com/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster/

The query looks like:

```
select * 
from users
where id in (select round(random() * 21e6)::integer as id
             from generate_series(1, 110)
             group by id -- Discard duplicates
            )
limit 100
```

However for SQL Server, I got errors like:

> 'random' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Do we have some SQL Server counter part of this fast sampling method? Thanks.

I tried edit as:

```
select top 100 * from users
    where id in (
      select round(RAND() * 21e6) CAST integer as id
      from generate_series(1, 110)
      group by id -- Discard duplicates
    )
```

still having error:

```
The round function requires 2 to 3 arguments.
```

Comment: Also: `limit` is not a supported keyword in T-SQL - you need to use `SELECT TOP(n) *` instead

Comment: Just use top 100 order by newid()

Comment: @SeanLange, for some very large table, order by the newid(), takes 3 hours....

Comment: How large are those tables? I just did a quick test on a table with 100 million rows and returned those in less than 3 seconds. I you don't need an exact 100 rows you might look at TABLESAMPLE.

Comment: @SeanLange, TABLESAMPLE solved my problem!! that table is probably in the scale of trillions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Sean's comment: TABLESAMPLE . Would be the solution, now it is extremely fast to sample.

Comment: Cool glad that works for you. One caveat is that TABLESAMPLE will not always return exactly 100 (or whatever) rows.

Comment: @SeanLange, Thanks! I realized TABLESAMPLE actually returns me random pages, like random blocks of data. Is it possible for it to be more random, like random page of size 1? (currently it looks like it is returning random pages of size 100, or blocks of 100)

Comment: Not that I know of. It works how it works from MS. It is a bit strange for sure but makes this type of thing pretty fast.

Comment: @SeanLange, I see! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

For T-SQL it is RAND(), not RANDOM()

Also, apart from the comment regarding having to use TOP(n) instead of limit - you also have to use CAST or CONVERT for the data type conversion. And generate_series is not a built-in function in sql server.

Comment: There are so many other things in that query that don't work in t-sql.